# PHP form method post with action URL

Tags: forms, post, get, action

I have the following problem with my form.

The form looks like:

```
<form name='add'
      method='post'
      action='<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) ?><?php echo "?naujiena=".$_GET['pavadinimas']."" ?>' >

    <input name='id' type='hidden'>
    <input name='skaicius' type='hidden'>
    <input name='pavadinimas' type='text'>
    <input type='submit' name='prideti' value='prideti'>
</form>
```

After the form confirmation I see the result in the URL like this:

```
http://viper.us.lt/php/naujiena/forma.php?naujiena=
```

It should be like this:

```
http://viper.us.lt/php/naujiena/forma.php?naujiena=some_value
```

Comment: Obvious question, are you sure your GET variable contains anything? I don't think you need the `.""` at the end either.

Answer (score 3):

Change the form method from POST to GET like this:

```
<form name='add' method='GET' action='<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) ?><?php echo "?naujiena=".$_GET['pavadinimas']."" ?>' >
```

Comment: It's not working, because the values don't insert in database.

Comment: Why should it be changed from POST to GET?

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is wrong. You don't need the `<?php echo "?naujiena=".$_GET['pavadinimas']."" ?>` on the `action` `attribute`.

Just change your `method` from `POST` to `GET`, and after `submit` (type) `button` is clicked, you will see the value on the `URL`, and will be able to get the value as `$_GET`.

---

**Edited**:

Then you need your form like

```
<form name="add" method="post" id="myForm" action="garissuero.html" onsubmit="changeActionURL()">
        <input name="id" type="hidden" />
        <input name="skaicius" type="hidden" />
        <input name="pavadinimas" id="pavadinimas" type="text" />
        <input type="submit" name="prideti" value="prideti" />
</form>
```

And have a `javascript` code like:

```
function changeActionURL() {
    var forma = document.getElementById('myForm');
    forma.action += "?naujiena=" + document.getElementById('pavadinimas').value;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mETwZ/2/

Comment: I need only see naujienos name in action ! Not others

Comment: Man, you want me to go to your computer? Did you even check the JSFiddle page I gave you?

Comment: Maybe it's possible to do with objects?

Comment: Why is JavaScript required for this?